# There is no ViewData item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

good morning, i'm a beginner with the language vb.net and asp.net , i'm getting this exception and i want to know where i should define this ViewData item...

the exception:

`There is no ViewData item of type "IEnumerable <SelectListItem>" with key "typeId."`

the line of  code where the exception refers to :

```
<label>Type: @Html.DropDownList("typeId", DirectCast(ViewBag.Type, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), New With { key.id = "typeId" })</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller certainly, before calling the view.
Here, you have ViewBag.Type, but it seems you never defined this property.

Before calling View in controller, add a line where you set ViewBag.Type

Something like :

```
ViewBag.Type = new List<SelectListItem>() ...
```

Sorry, this is C#, but you are certainly able to convert it to VB (I don't remember exactly how generics work)

EDIT:

VB Version :

```
ViewBag.Type = New List(Of SelectListItem)()
```

Thanks @DominicKexel

Comment: @Kek `ViewBag.Type = New List(Of SelectListItem)()`